# Function reference arguments in json format (actually, object literal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, arguments

Is it possible add an argument to a function reference in an object literal:

```
var custom = {onLoadBegin: onLoadBegin};
```

Would like it to be

```
onLoadBegin('argument')
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question. It's unclear how custom object and the function call are actually related and what you mean by adding an argument in a json object.

Comment: That's not even a JSON object. JSON objects can't hold funtions. You're dealing with an Object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a function named `onLoadBegin` that is external to `custom`, then you could do this:

```
var custom = {
    onLoadBegin: function() {
        onLoadBegin("argument");
    }
};
```

When you call `custom.onLoadBegin` it will invoke the original `onLoadBegin` with your argument.

Comment: I am now doing this, but another issue has crept up:         onLoadComplete: function() { onLoadComplete($(this).attr('id')) },  - the $(this) doesn't seem to be available at that point in time, how do I fix that? The argument is not static.

Comment: @Wesley - The value of `this` depends on how your custom `onLoadBegin` function is invoked. For example, if it's by saying `custom.onLoadBegin()` then `this` refers to `custom`. If you want the value of `this` from some other context, then you need to make that explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your example you could call `custom.onLoadBegin(argument)`

Comment: I can't call it myself, it would need to be done automatically as it relies on other jquery plugins to do the calling.

Answer (score 0):

the JSON format does not include functions, it's just for data. Please provide extra information about *what exactly you want to achieve*

If you don't care about the standard and you just want to get stuff done, you can do it like this:

```
{functionName: [argument1, argument2, ...]}
```

And on the client side, do something like this:

```
window[key].apply(this, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your handler in a closure:

```
var loadHandler = function() {
  doSomething('argument');
}

onLoadBegin( loadHandler );
```

You can also do this with an anonymous function:

```
onLoadBegin( function() { 
  doSomething('argument');
});
```